# Angular Auth Guard secure routes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to secure my routes by using `auth-guard`.

My problem is if the user is logged in. The user cant go to sign in/ sign up page and must redirect the user to default page.

**routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
 { path: 'list-users', component: ListUsersComponent, canActivate: 
 [AuthGuardService] }
];
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
  console.log('go to login');
  return false;
}
console.log('has access');
return true;
```

I tried make the code look like this but i get an infinite loop.

```
if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
  console.log('go to login');
  return false;
} else {
  console.log('redirect when loggedin to list-users');
  this.router.navigate(['list-users']); // infinite loop
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What's with the downvote ?

Comment: you are applying auth-guard to "list-users" and you are navigating to "list-users" if the user is logged-in, obviously it is leading to an infinite loop, what's wrong with the first snippet of auth-guard code without the else part, that should work.

Comment: @wolverine problem is the loggedin user can still access the signin & signup page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two services

anonymous-guard.ts

```
if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
 this.router.navigate(['/']);
 return false;
} else {
 return true;
}
```

authenticated-guard-ts

```
if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
   this.router.navigate(['list-users']);
   return false;
} else {
   retrun true;
}
```

then apply it to routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: LoginComponent,canActivate: 
 [AuthenticatedGuardService] },
 { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent,canActivate: 
 [AuthenticatedGuardService] },
 { path: 'list-users', component: ListUsersComponent, canActivate: 
 [AnonymousGuardService] }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is if the user is logged in. The user cant go to sign in/ sign up page and must redirect the user to default page.

You can simply check if user is accessing /login or /signup route (however you named it).

You have created an infinite loop because 
`this.router.navigate(['list-users']);` is recursively calling the auth guard, which in turns, executes the "else" block and navigates user back to list-users which calls auth-guard again and so on.

**AuthGuard.ts**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
  if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) { //user is not logged in
    this.router.navigate(['/']); //go to login
    return false;
  } else { //user is logged in

    if(state.url.indexOf("/login") > 0 || state.url.indexOf("/signup") > 0 ){ //check if logged in user is accessing /login or /signup path
      this.router.navigate('['list-users']');
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm do I need to import the `state` because its undefine.

Comment: Yes, you need to import `RouterStateSnapshot` from `'@angular/router'`

Comment: A better pattern would probably be to encapsulate /login and /signin in a separate module (e.g. accounts module that is accessed via /acc). You would then use `canLoad` instead of `canActivate` to check if user can lazily load that module.